# Accessibility code is not working

Tags: java

I'm trying to code a GUI with getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName()
The code compiles, but my screen reader "JAWS" won't read anything except the title of the window.
I even tried clicking the buttons with mouse, but still won't read the button text.

Normally, on pressing the shift key, I should jump between buttons, and screen reader should read.

BTW, You don't need "JAWS" to test the code. You can use Windows Naraator. It's under "All programs" > Accessories > Accessibility > Narrator
That doesn't read the buttons either.

Here's the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import javax.accessibility.*;


public class ggi{

public static void main( String args[] ){

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize( 400, 200 );
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.getRootPane().setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(4, 4, 4, 4, Color.BLACK));
frame.setTitle(" Testing access ");
frame.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName(" I am testing accessibility ");
frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
frame.setResizable( false );

JPanel panel= new JPanel();
frame.getContentPane().add( panel );
panel.setBackground( new Color( 100, 100, 100 ) );
panel.setLayout( null );
panel.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName(" This is a panel ");

JButton startR= new JButton(" Start ");
startR.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName(" Start  ");
panel.add(startR);
startR.setBackground( Color.black );
startR.setForeground( Color.white );
startR.setBorderPainted(false);
startR.setFocusPainted( false );
startR.setBounds( 10, 10 , 100, 25 );
startR.setToolTipText(" start New ");


final JButton stopR= new JButton("Stop ");
stopR.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName(" Stop  ");
panel.add( stopR );
stopR.setBounds( 150, 10 , 100, 25 );
stopR.setBackground( Color.black );
stopR.setForeground( Color.white );
//startR.setContentAreaFilled(false);
stopR.setBorderPainted(false);
stopR.setFocusPainted( false );
stopR.setToolTipText(" Stop  ");

}//main
}//class
```